# jQuery Deferreds, .pipe and exceptions

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception, jquery-deferred

I have code that looks somewhat like this (less ridiculous, of course):

```
var d = $.Deferred();
d.pipe(function() {
    throw "a";
}).then(function() {
    console.log("good!");
}, function(e) {
    console.log("I want the exception here");
});
d.resolve();
```

The problem is that throwing an exception in a `.pipe` `doneFilter` does not seem to make jQuery consider it as a failure and it results in an uncaught exception in the `doneFilter`.

An alternative is to create a new deferred and throw a try-catch block around the `doneFilter`, but I was wondering if there was a better way to go about it.

Comment: I'm confused because your example does not use either `.pipe()` or `doneFilter` which you then go on to talk about `\-:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to use `throw`, it is indeed best to catch it in the `doneFilter`, and `return $.Deferred().reject('a')` (or whatever) from it on error. The fail callback in `then` will then be called with the arg you pass.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? There's apparently no such thing as `$.Deferred.reject`.

Comment: Sorry, typo. Edited to fix: `$.Deferred()`

Comment: Why isn't this default behavior :-( https://github.com/kriskowal/q has it by default.

Comment: Here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13611929/123897) is a good comparison between Promises/A and jQuery Deferred.